# LocationService.FusedLocation returning null only on some devices

Tags: java, android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am trying to get the last known location of the user.

After Google API is connected, I call my function:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    initilizeMap();
}
```

The function looks like this:

```
private void initilizeMap(){
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null){
        ...
    }else{
        // location unknown
    }
}
```

I opened up the Google maps first to get the current location of the user. However, `mLastLocation` is still null.

The most interesting thing is that the code is working on Sony tablet. But I changed my phone today to Nexus and it is not working on this device!

How can I fix this?

P.S. I included these permissions in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and android version is 6.0.1

Comment: Looks like the code is okay, maybe it has to do with your phone?

Comment: @EricS. I hope it is not! I just bought it :( Google maps is working though

Comment: I'm sure your phone is fine, I thought maybe a setting or something.

Comment: Location is on! What else can it be?

Comment: Did you request the permissions?

Comment: @Pztar, I included necessary permissions in the manifest file. I manually enabled the Location in the device! Do you mean this? Just in case, android version is 6.0.1

Comment: No, If you're running Android 6.0 or higher you need to request runtime permissions. http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Oh yeah that must be it. It should've shown a red-squiggly warning on Android Studio, but it'll let you compile. I remember I had the same problem last month. @Pztar you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Pztar, that was it! I checked to see if user granted a permission. If not, I requested it. Then it went to work just as expected! Thanks a ton! If you will post it as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any dangerous permissions as listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permission-groups) need to be requested at run time, as shown on [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) otherwise you'll get a `Permission Denied` error which can have unexpected results in your app.

You check a permission with:
`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)`

it can return either `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` or `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`

if you get a `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` then you can request that permission with:

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION);`

where `MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION` is your defined `int` variable that is passed to the callback of `onRequestPermissionsResult` where you handle the outcome of the permission allow/deny.